# Continually Rasterize + Write On effect causes layer to disappear

Tags: after-effects

I created a layer from Adobe Illustrator by importing an AI file into After Effects. Then I added the Write On effect and created a "grow" animation. I then clicked the "Continuously Rasterize" icon so that when I scale my image up, it doesn't become pixelated. However when I select that Icon, my layer becomes hidden from the preview window. What's going on? Why does AE hide my layer instead of making it crisp?

I am using After Effects & Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the write-on effect causes a layer to become pixels (bitmapped), not vectors (I'm sure there's a better way to phrase this).

Comment: Rasterize [means](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/47083) to convert to pixels.

Comment: oops - yes, never post first thing in the morning... fixed...

Comment: You could work around it by making the write-on effect on a solid and then using it as a track matte